# Can participles be used like this?

Tags: writing, participles

There are many glasses which were not made from broken glass. They are just made this way. Can I call them 'broken glass'? If not, should I just say 'glasses'?

Comment: What do you mean? If they weren't broken, they're not broken glass.

Comment: @OmarL In games, there are no scenes glass broke but they are named 'broken glass'

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @OmarL There's no context glass broke, but in game an avatar said he found broken glass which was stolen from monsters...but the point is that he's never seen the glass broke, but say 'broken glass'

Comment: _Broken glass_ would describe jagged pieces of glass which obviously come from a glass object which has been smashed. Even if you didn't witness the breakage, you can see that it has happened.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks for always helping me!