# Is ‘broken glass’ ambiguous?

Tags: participles

Can ‘Broken glass’ mean:

1. Glass was broken but it’s fixed after then.
2. Glass was broken but it’s not fixed after then.

If so, how can I express sentence 2 in a way easy to understand?

Comment: Related to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/275587/can-participles-be-used-like-this ?

Comment: @Kate Bunting The writer is me :) I wanted some clarity!

Comment: Yes, I know that - I wondered why you were asking almost the same question twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, "broken" refers to things that are currently broken.

For glass specifically, there's mostly no practical way to fix glass to the point of removing the breakage, so it tends to remain that way regardless of attempts to fix it. Generally, one would *replace* broken glass with new, unbroken glass, so the new glass isn't glass that was broken, but is now fixed.

Even more generally, though, "broken" tends to refer to things that are *currently* broken: one would not say they have "a broken leg" after it has healed, or "a broken car" after it's been repaired.  One might refer to "a *previously broken* leg" if they wanted to differentiate that from "currently broken."